# SQL Server - add efficiency to this stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I inherited the following stored procedure from my company's former DBA - it is meant to write records from a holding table (Transfer.CaptureSync) to a Production table (Data.Capture) based on certain conditions:

```
USE [Production_Search]
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SyncDataFromHolding]
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @taskSourceId bigint,
    @syncBatch uniqueidentifier = newid()

DECLARE curSources cursor
FOR
SELECT TaskSourceId
FROM [Transfer].CaptureSync
GROUP BY TaskSourceId

OPEN curSources

fetch next from curSources
into @taskSourceId

while @@fetch_status = 0
begin

-- insert the rows into capture table, but do not flag as active
INSERT INTO [Data].Capture (
    [TaskSourceId]
    ,[Url]
    ,[Identify]
    ,[Name]
    ,[Entity]
    ,[Sources]
    ,[CaptureBatch]
    ,[IsActive]
    ,[CaptureDateTime]
    ,[SyncBatchId]
    )
SELECT [TaskSourceId]
    ,[Url]
    ,[Identify]
    ,[Name]
    ,[Entity]
    ,[Sources]
    ,[CaptureBatch]
    ,0 -- isActive
    ,[CaptureDateTime]
    ,@syncBatch -- SyncBatchId
FROM [Transfer].CaptureSync
WHERE TaskSourceId = @taskSourceId

-- flag the new rows as active
UPDATE [Data].Capture
SET IsActive = 1
WHERE TaskSourceId = @taskSourceId
    AND SyncBatchId = @syncBatch

-- remove the existing rows
DELETE [Data].Capture
WHERE TaskSourceId = @taskSourceId
    AND SyncBatchId != @syncBatch

-- get the next source
fetch next from curSources
into @taskSourceId

end -- end of the cursor

close curSources
deallocate curSources

END
GO
```

We run this every 24 hours.  The issue is that it takes almost **12 hours** for this stored procedure to complete execution.  The daily number of records written approximate 1 million.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this kind of insert so we can greatly reduce the amount of time it takes this to complete?  I read that SSIS packages are much faster than Inserts via stored procedures, but I don't know that an SSIS package could actually accomplish what this stored procedure is doing.

Comment: SQL databases are good at doing bulk operations. Generally, if you can avoid doing lots of repeated queries in a loop and instead rewrite the logic as a single query, then it will run considerably faster.

Can you write a single INSERT statement which copies all of the relevant rows across, instead of doing a query for each different TaskSourceId value? Can you do the 'flag the new rows as active' update as part of that same query (setting the flag as you insert the rows)? Can you then write a single DELETE statement which removes all of the appropriate rows from the Capture  table?

Comment: >The issue is that it takes almost 12 hours 

Why does it take that long?  What do the [Wait Stats][1] tell you?



  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-wait-stats-transact-sql

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  Wait Stats are new to me, so bear with me here: I'm getting this error when trying to run the wait stats: "The request for procedure 'dm_os_wait_stats' failed because 'dm_os_wait_stats' is a view object."  This is an Azure SQL Database and I'm the db admin with full permissions (or maybe not, based on this  error message!)

Comment: On Azure SQL Database, look at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-wait-stats-azure-sql-database

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft ok thank you.  I've successfully run the stats.  So now I have 36 rows and 5 columns of data.  Can you offer some guidance on what I'm looking for in these results? Thanks.

Comment: The 12 hours of stored procedure runtime are comprised of CPU time and waits.  That view shows the accumulated waits by wait type.  You can get a rough idea by looking at the top 10 waits, or you can capture the waits over multiple snapshots during your query execution to see _why_ it's taking 12 hours.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft  So the top 5, which seem to comprise the majority of the time, are PAGEIOLATCH_EX, LOG_RATE_GOVERNOR, ASYNC_NETWORK_IO, SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD, and PAGEIOLATCH_SH.  Do any of those jump out at you as something I should or can tweak?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the biggest issue is that you are then performing separate queries **for each individual TaskSourceId**.

You are using this cursor to iterate through your `CaptureSync` table.

```
DECLARE curSources cursor
FOR
SELECT TaskSourceId
FROM [Transfer].CaptureSync
GROUP BY TaskSourceId
```

You are then performing separate queries **for each individual row** in those results, by doing this:

```
fetch next from curSources
into @taskSourceId
```

You could gain quite a bit of efficiency here if instead you used some logic to process the whole batch in just one go **without using the cursor**.

For example, for the first insert, you could just do:

```
INSERT INTO [Data].Capture (
   ... fields ....
SELECT [TaskSourceId], 
   ... etc ....
FROM [Transfer].CaptureSync
WHERE TaskSourceId IS NOT NULL
```

This will actually insert all rows in `CaptureSync` into `Capture` which seems to be the intended behaviour of your logic, right?

(I added the condition to check that `TaskSourceId` is not null just in case there are some since I think those rows would not have been processed by your current logic)

You should then see how you could update the data (and delete old rows) also in one go.

For example, if your `@syncBatch` does not repeat, you could use just that value to identify the new rows, like so:

```
-- flag the new rows as active
UPDATE [Data].Capture
SET IsActive = 1
WHERE SyncBatchId = @syncBatch
```

And then:

```
-- remove the existing rows
DELETE [Data].Capture
WHERE SyncBatchId != @syncBatch
```

Basically, you should try to run this as just one bulk instead of iterating each row individually, that should speed this up dramatically.

Comment: Eugenioy, thanks for the efforts of writing this up.  From what I can understand as far as the intended behavior, I don't think the author was trying to write ALL records from CaptureSync to Capture.  I think he was attempting some kind of de-duplication.  Not all records in CaptureSync are new every 24 hours. You're certainly correct that using cursor and iterating row-by-row is what's taking so much time. But I wish I knew WHY he felt the need to build the procedure that way.  My understanding is that he was a highly-experienced DBA. So I'm a little wary of eliminating the cursor completely.

Comment: They might be a highly-experienced DBA but their focus might be on operational activity - backups, restore, HA, etc and development is a complete and utter mystery to them